# Should I document a "return callback()" as return value if it is not intended to be used?

Tags: jsdoc

I have a piece of code which returns nothing useful:

```
/**
 * Close the web server
 *
 * @param {function} callback - Called after web server is stopped
 */
PolyApp.prototype.stop = function(callback) {
  if (!this._listeningServer) {
    if (callback) {
      return callback();
    }

    return;
  }

  this._listeningServer.close(callback);
};
```

This function makes use of return to control the execution flow. Given it returns nothing useful I want to avoid documenting it. That gives me the following benefits:

- The documentation is more clear as it documents the intention of use
- The code is less cluttered with comments that provide no value
- I avoid signing a contract of returning something that I do not want to maintain.

On the other hand:

- I am returning a value which is not being documented

I think that I should not document it as I do not want people to rely on any returning behavior.

What do you think about? Am I doing right being pragmatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to document is up to you. You have to ask yourself the question: "Will I, or other people, ever need to see this documentation to get additional knowledge?". In the case of callbacks that don't need any specific return behavior, you don't need to document anything of it. You should speficy for *stop* that it'll return whatever the callback returns. People might get confused otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, EinsteinK. Your words have a lot of sense for me. If no better answer is provided I will accept yours.